# What type are file objects in Python?

Tags: python, types, filehandle, isinstance

How can I use `isinstance` to determine the 'type' of a file object, such as in the expression:

```py
>>> open(file)
```

Comment: What do you mean by judging the type of open(file)? Do you mean the type of the text in the file(e.g. int, string)?

Comment: If you encounter this question looking for an appropriate type hint in Python3, use TextIO imported from `typing` (e.g. `from typing import TextIO` in the "preamble" and then `file_handle : TextIO = open(...)` in your code.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In Python 3.x, normal file objects are of type [`io.TextIOWrapper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper):

```
>>> type(open('file.txt'))
<class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>

>>> from io import TextIOWrapper
>>> isinstance(open('file.txt'), TextIOWrapper)
True
```

In Python 2.x, all file objects are of type [`file`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#file):

```
>>> type(open('file.txt'))
<type 'file'>

>>> isinstance(open('file.txt'), file)
True
```

Comment: Most of the time, you don't really care, though. You care that it's an iterable of lines, or that it has a `read` method or a `write` method, or something else relating to the file interface. That's what you should be checking, usually by simply trying to use the object like a file and catching the error if it doesn't support the interface you need.

Comment: FYI, open a file in binary mode `open('file.txt', 'rb')` results in  `<class '_io.BufferedReader'>` type.

Comment: `TextIOWrapper` is what is returned if you open in default/ text mode, `BufferedReader` is what you get in binary ('b') mode, so you can check for either individually or just use their superclass `IOBase` if you want to catch both

Answer (score 11):

One can pick their preference from the [IO class hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#class-hierarchy). This answer builds upon the previous answer by user2555451 and its comments. The one-line summary is at the end of the answer.

For **text files**, [`io.TextIOBase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase) can be acceptable:

```py
>>> import io

>>> type(f := open('/tmp/foo', 'w'))
<class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>
>>> isinstance(f, io.TextIOBase)
True

>>> f.__class__.__bases__
(<class '_io._TextIOBase'>,)
>>> f.__class__.__mro__
(<class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>, <class '_io._TextIOBase'>, <class '_io._IOBase'>, <class 'object'>)
```

For text files, avoid `io.TextIOWrapper` because it does not also work for `io.StringIO`:

```py
>>> isinstance(io.StringIO('foo'), io.TextIOWrapper)
False
>>> isinstance(io.StringIO('foo'), io.TextIOBase)
True
```

For **binary files**, [`io.BufferedIOBase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedIOBase) can be acceptable:

```py
>>> import io

>>> type(f := open('/tmp/foo', 'wb'))
<class '_io.BufferedWriter'>
>>> isinstance(f, io.BufferedIOBase)
True

>>> f.__class__.__bases__
(<class '_io._BufferedIOBase'>,)
>>> f.__class__.__mro__
(<class '_io.BufferedWriter'>, <class '_io._BufferedIOBase'>, <class '_io._IOBase'>, <class 'object'>)
```

For binary files, avoid `io.BufferedReader` or `io.BufferedWriter` because they do not also work for `io.BytesIO`:

```py
>>> isinstance(io.BytesIO(b'foo'), io.BufferedReader)
False
>>> isinstance(io.BytesIO(b'foo'), io.BufferedWriter)
False
>>> isinstance(io.BytesIO(b'foo'), io.BufferedIOBase)
True
```

To support **both text and binary files**, [`io.IOBase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase) is acceptable:

```py
>>> import io

>>> isinstance(open('/tmp/foo', 'w'), io.IOBase)
True
>>> isinstance(open('/tmp/foo', 'wb'), io.IOBase)
True
```

In summary, I would typically pick [`io.TextIOBase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase) for text files, [`io.BufferedIOBase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedIOBase) for binary files, and [`io.IOBase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase) for nonspecific files.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [the documentation for `open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open):

> Open a file, returning an object of the [`file`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#file) type described in section [*File Objects*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects).

Thus, `open` returns a `file`, and you should use `isinstance(foo, file)`

Answer (score 0):

Its type is `file`.  You can tell by the output of `type(open("file","w"))`

Comment: This is outdated.