# The correct way to annotate a "file type" in Python

Tags: python, python-3.5, type-hinting

In modern versions of Python one can have static type analysis using function annotations, according to [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/). This is made easy through the typing module.

Now I'm wondering how I would give a "type hint" towards a "filestream".

```
def myfunction(file: FILETYPE):
    pass

with open(fname) as file:
    myfunction(file)
```

What would I insert as `FILETYPE`?

Using `print(type(file))` returns `<class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>` which isn't clear at all.

Isn't there a generic "file" type?

Comment: Must the annotation refer to a physical file on disk, or can it also include file-like objects like `StringIO`?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38569401, https://stackoverflow.com/q/24501462

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can use `typing.IO`, `typing.TextIO`, and `typing.BinaryIO` to represent different types of I/O streams. To quote the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.IO):

> сlass typing.IO
> class typing.TextIO
> class typing.BinaryIO
>
> Generic type `IO[AnyStr]` and its subclasses `TextIO(IO[str])` and `BinaryIO(IO[bytes])` represent the types of I/O streams such as
> returned by [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).

Comment: `typing.IO`, `typing.TextIO`, and `typing.BinaryIO` is deprecated since version 3.8, will be removed in version 3.12 per typing [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.IO).

Comment: @lead-free I believe the deprecation note only applies to the *`typing.io` namespace*. See [this](https://bugs.python.org/issue42001) and [this](https://bugs.python.org/issue38291).

Comment: Though it seems that there is currently no alternative to `typing.io` that mypy would respect (`io.IOBase` and it's children).

Comment: @EugeneYarmash is right. Here's the actual deprecation message from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.IO): "The `typing.io` *namespace* is deprecated and will be removed. **These types should be directly imported from** `typing` **instead.**"

Answer (score 19):

I think you want [`io.IOBase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase), "[t]he abstract base class for all I/O classes, acting on streams of bytes."

Note that this includes also in-memory streams like `io.StringIO` and `io.BytesIO`. Read the documentation on the [module `io`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html) for details.

Comment: Just as a comment: while this is the "best" answer I might get. The problem is still not solved with this. A lot of things depend on _io._base and derivatives from that. There is no "generic" top layer for both `_io._base` and `io.base` though?

Comment: @paul23 I don't understand what you mean. AFAIK `io.IOBase` is the best type hint towards a "bytestream" and every file-like object that can be created using the standard library is an instance of it. If `IOBase` does not match your idea of a bytestream or you have a use case where it's not a good type hint you might want to edit your question and explain why.

Comment: for example if you open a in memory byte stream with BytesIO; This derives from `_BufferedIOBase` which derives from `_IOBase`

Comment: @paul23 How is that a problem? Just in case you didn't notice,  `io.BytesIO` also inherits from `io.IOBase`.

Answer (score 6):

Either this:

```
from typing import TextIO # or IO or BinaryIO

def myfunction(file: TextIO ):
    pass
```

**OR** this

```
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from typing import TextIO # or IO or BinaryIO

def myfunction(file: 'TextIO'):
    pass
```

The second approach would avoid to import the class during execution. Although python would still have to import `TYPE_CHECKING` during execution, it is a good practice to avoid importing classes for type hinting only:  (1) doesn't get executed (just parsed), and (2) **it could avoid cyclic imports**.

Comment: Given one of the goals on the type hinting PEP [484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#rationale-and-goals), I don't see why it's a good practice to avoid imports for type hints.

Answer (score 1):

[typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed) has a `SupportsRead` protocol:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING, AnyStr

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from _typeshed import SupportsRead


def takes_readable_str(fo: SupportsRead[str]):
    return fo.read()

def takes_readable_bytes(fo: SupportsRead[bytes]):
    return fo.read()

def takes_readable_any(fo: SupportsRead[AnyStr]):
    return fo.read()
```

Comment: I would say that a private module `_typeshed` should not be used. Is not the module intended only for developers of type checker tools?

Comment: are we not effectively developers of a custom type checker tool for ourselves, in this case? Python type checking is optional, hence the `if TYPE_CHECKING`.