# Type hint for python function with side effect (write to file), and no return value

Tags: python, types, type-hinting

What is the correct type hint for the following function (and why), given that the function is a 'side-effect' only function, that has no return value?

```py
from os import PathLike
from typing import Union


def write_to_file(n: int, file: Union[str, bytes, PathLike[str]]) -> '?????':
    with open(file, 'w') as f:
        file.write(n)

write_to_file(3, 'file.txt')
```

????? =

- None
- typing.IO
- other?

Comment: That function does have a return value, `None`.

Comment: Also, `file: typing.IO` won't type check. The first argument to `open` needed to be `Union[str, bytes, PathLike[str]]`, not an existing IO stream. See [PEP-519](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0519/) for more details about type hinting paths.

Comment: true I forget that not declaring return defaults behind the scenes to return None. So I guess the answer to set None as the type hint

Comment: @Brian https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41748896/the-correct-way-to-annotate-a-file-type-in-python , seems to suggest to use typing.IO etc

Comment: That post recommends using [`typing.IO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.IO) and company to type hint the stream _returned_ by `open`, not the file path that you pass to `open`.

Comment: @tuatara, that's because it is a file handle in that answer, it's already been opened. In this question, that would be the type of `f` rather than `file`.

Comment: Okay thanks for the clarifications I will also edit the question to reflect proper type hinting for the file