# Python, `pathlib.Path.open()` method and built-in function `open()` don't return instances of `typing.IO`

Tags: python-3.x, typechecking

I've read some [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41748896/the-correct-way-to-annotate-a-file-type-in-python), and they seem contradictory to what happens IRL.

Try the following:

```py
from typing import IO
from pathlib import Path

example_path = Path(r"D:\Example.txt")
with example_path.open("r") as f:
    print(isinstance(f, IO))
with open(example_path) as f:
    print(isinstance(f, IO))
```

It will print:

```
False
False
```

That's baffling, because according to [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.IO), it seems to me that one of the very purposes of `typing.IO` is for type-checking an object for `IO` type, and this would include the use of `isinstance()`. Why doesn't it work? Doesn't that defeat the very purpose? What am I missing here?